# Compact Urysohn condition and $\sigma$-compact implies normal.

Tags: general-topology

Throughout $X$ will denote Hausdorff space.

Following notation will be used :

> Let $A$ closed set and $B$ open set containing $A$. Suppose continuous $f:X\to [0,1] $ is such that $f\equiv 1$ on $A$ and $f \equiv 0 $ outside $B$. Such $f$ will be denoted $A\prec f \prec B $

Compact Urysohn condition will be defined as follows :

> Given compact $K$ and open $V$ with $K \subset V$, there exists $f$ such that $K\prec f \prec V$.

Urysohn condition can be defined likewise substituting "closed" in place of "compact" in above definition. So Urysohn condition is equivalent with $X$ being normal.

My question is :

> If $X$ is $\sigma$ -compact and satisfies compact Urysohn condition, then $X$ satisfies Urysohn condition, hence is normal?

Given closed $A$ and open $V$, it is possible to choose countable chain $\{K_i\}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}  $of compact sets such that its union is equal to $A$. Choosing Urysohn function for each $K_i\subset V$, I make this naive guess that it might be possible to approximate the sequence of Urysohn functions to some $A\prec f \prec V $.

Comment: You mean $f \equiv 1$ on $A$ and $f \equiv 0$ outside $B$?

Comment: @frafour oh yeah. I made mistake with that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this follows from standard results:

The compact-Urysohn condition implies regularity (even complete regularity). And $X$ is Lindelöf (follows easily from $\sigma$-compactness).

And a regular Lindelöf space is normal.

A direct proof: if $F$ is closed and $U$ is an open neighbourhood of $F$, then $F$ is $\sigma$-compact (like $X$) and so we can write $X=\cup_{n=1}^\infty K_n$ where all $K_n$ are compact. We can find continuous $f_n: X \to [0,1]$ such that $K_n \prec f_n \prec U$ and then define $f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} f_n(x)$ and note that $f: X \to [0,1]$ is continuous and $F \prec f \prec U$.